# Analyse charging circuit for a small voice recorder

Tags: charging, lipo

I'm trying to analyse a miniature MP3 audio voice recorder power/charging circuit.
By examining the PCB I've managed to produce this schematic.
Some of it looks clear to me.

**J1 disconnected from USB and SW1 is in position Rec On:**

1. The gate of Q2 (P channel mosfet) is near ground so the LIPO cell is
   able to supply IC1 (pin 4) and thus power the rest of the circuit.
2. IC1_Pin12 is then held high so Q3 then also latches Q2 gate low.

**J1 disconnected from USB and SW1 is in position Rec Off:**

1. IC1_Pin11 is pulled low.
2. Q2 gate is still pulled low via Q3. After X ms, presumably enough
   time to  cleanly close down, IC1_pin 12 drops low and the power is
   shut off.

Here is not so clear to me:

**J1 connected to USB (+5V) and SW1 is in position Rec Off:**

1. The LIPO charges through the Q2 body diode ? Can this be so ?
2. IC1 then exposes the SD card to the USB connection to allow files to be read via a PC etc.

**J1 connected to USB (+5V) and SW1 is in position Rec On:**

1. According to the instructions, you should not do this.
   Can this cause a conflict or is it protected against ?

Unfortunately, I have no data sheet for IC1. I can make only some assumptions about its behaviour.

[image: Voice Recorder power/charging circuit]
Edit:
A 1M resistor between Q2 S and G is missing from the schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems body diode charges LiPo limited by R4, such that if LiPo is at 3V and Vf=0.7 est. , If=(5-0.7-3)V/4.7ohms = 0.277A  Pd= 0.2W

It may cause a glitch on drain during contact transient via Coss charge, so perhaps not recommended during Record to avoid USB current demand error??